# my app keeps crashing with no errors before run time

Tags: java, android, xml

Below is my app and what I want to do is to have a list with images and be able to filter the list and the filtered list is clickable. It was working fine when I was using the mainActivity and its content_main.xml. But I decided to use Fragments and now it stop working. What I did was to create a new Fragment called HomePage.java so I can display a listview on one of the fragments and then use other fragments to do other stuff. but it keeps crashing and I cannot figure out why.

Here is the running process:

```
W/ResourceType: Skipping entry 0x105007e in package table 0 because it is not complex!
W/ResourceType: Skipping entry 0x105007e in package table 0 because it is not complex!
W/ResourceType: Skipping entry 0x105007e in package table 0 because it is not complex!
W/ResourceType: Skipping entry 0x105007e in package table 0 because it is not complex!
W/ResourceType: Skipping entry 0x105007e in package table 0 because it is not complex!
W/ResourceType: Skipping entry 0x105007e in package table 0 because it is not complex!
W/ResourceType: Skipping entry 0x105007e in package table 0 because it is not complex!
W/ResourceType: Skipping entry 0x105007e in package table 0 because it is not complex!
W/ResourceType: Skipping entry 0x105007e in package table 0 because it is not complex!
W/ResourceType: Skipping entry 0x105007e in package table 0 because it is not complex!
W/ResourceType: Skipping entry 0x105007e in package table 0 because it is not complex!
W/ResourceType: Skipping entry 0x105007e in package table 0 because it is not complex!
W/ResourceType: Skipping entry 0x105007e in package table 0 because it is not complex!
W/ResourceType: Skipping entry 0x105007e in package table 0 because it is not complex!
W/ResourceType: Skipping entry 0x105007e in package table 0 because it is not complex!
W/ResourceType: Skipping entry 0x105007e in package table 0 because it is not complex!
W/ResourceType: Skipping entry 0x105007e in package table 0 because it is not complex!
W/ResourceType: Skipping entry 0x105007e in package table 0 because it is not complex!
W/ResourceType: Skipping entry 0x105007e in package table 0 because it is not complex!
W/ResourceType: Skipping entry 0x105007e in package table 0 because it is not complex!
W/ResourceType: Skipping entry 0x105007e in package table 0 because it is not complex!
W/ResourceType: Skipping entry 0x105007e in package table 0 because it is not complex!
W/ResourceType: Skipping entry 0x105007e in package table 0 because it is not complex!
W/ResourceType: Skipping entry 0x105007e in package table 0 because it is not complex!
W/ResourceType: Skipping entry 0x105007e in package table 0 because it is not complex!
W/ResourceType: Skipping entry 0x105007e in package table 0 because it is not complex!
W/ResourceType: Skipping entry 0x105007e in package table 0 because it is not complex!
W/ResourceType: Skipping entry 0x105007e in package table 0 because it is not complex!
W/ResourceType: Skipping entry 0x105007e in package table 0 because it is not complex!
W/ResourceType: Skipping entry 0x105007e in package table 0 because it is not complex!
E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 186K, 9% free 8061K/8775K, paused 12ms+14ms, total 47ms
D/AbsListView: Get MotionRecognitionManager
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41ddd2a0)
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  java.lang.NullPointerException
                      at com.example.jermaine.jutc.HomePage.onCreateView(HomePage.java:144)
                      at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2189)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1299)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)
                      at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:757)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2355)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2146)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2098)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2008)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:710)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 3522 SIG: 9
Application terminated.
```

This is xml file that has the imageView and textView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ImageView

        android:id="@+id/list_icons"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:src="@drawable/eighta"/>




    <TextView

        android:id="@+id/list_letters"
        android:text="NAGGO HEAD"
        android:layout_below="@+id/icons"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/list_icons"/>


    <TextView

        android:id="@+id/list_description"
        android:text="Garveymead, Weschester,Portmore Toll, Hagle Park, "
        android:layout_below="@+id/list_letters"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/list_icons"/>

    <TextView

        android:id="@+id/bus_number"
        android:text="8A "
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/list_letters"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/list_icons"/>




</RelativeLayout>
```

This xml file has the Listview:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.jermaine.jutc.HomePage">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->



    <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
        android:id="@+id/txtsearch"
        android:queryHint="Enter bus number"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtsearch"
        android:id="@+id/my_listview"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:dividerHeight="10dp"
        android:divider="#ffffff"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />





</RelativeLayout>
```

Below is my list Adapter and filters the list:

```
package com.example.jermaine.jutc;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import static android.R.attr.filter;


/**
 * Created by jermaine on 2/17/17.
 */

public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

    /*private int imagess[];
    private String lettersss[];
    private String description[];
    private String bus_number[];*/

    private Context context;
    ArrayList<Route> routes;

    CustomFilter searchFilter; // to filter the results from search
    ArrayList<Route> routeFilter;// new array to contain filter results

    //CustomFilter searchFilter;

    /*int imageFilter[];
    String letterFilter[];
    String desFilter[];
    String numberFilter[];*/


    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public ListAdapter(Context ctx, ArrayList<Route> routes) {
        this.context = ctx;
        this.routes = routes;
        this.routeFilter = routes;


        //this.context = context;
        /*this.imagess = imagess;
        this.lettersss = lettersss;
        this.description = description;
        this.bus_number = bus_number;

        this.imageFilter = imagess;
        this.letterFilter = lettersss;
        this.desFilter = description;
        this.numberFilter =bus_number;*/


    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        //return bus_number.length;
        return routes.size();

    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        //return bus_number[position];
        return routes.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return routes.indexOf(getItem(position));
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View grid = convertView;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView == null) {

            grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

        }

        ImageView iconss = (ImageView) grid.findViewById(R.id.list_icons);
        TextView letterss = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.list_letters);
        TextView desss = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.list_description);
        TextView buses = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.bus_number);

        // set data to them
        iconss.setImageResource(routes.get(position).getImage());
        letterss.setText(routes.get(position).getTitle());
        desss.setText(routes.get(position).getDescription());
        buses.setText(routes.get(position).getRoutes());
        return grid;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {

        if(searchFilter == null){
            searchFilter = new CustomFilter();

        }

        return searchFilter;
    }

    //inner class to hangle what being filtered
    class CustomFilter extends Filter{

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            if(constraint !=null && constraint.length()>0){

                //contraint to uppercase
                constraint = constraint.toString().toUpperCase();
                ArrayList<Route> filters = new ArrayList<Route>();

                // get specific items
                for(int i =0; i<routeFilter.size(); i++){
                    //if what the user types matches in the filter list
                    if(routeFilter.get(i).getRoutes().toUpperCase().contains(constraint)){
                        Route r = new Route(routeFilter.get(i).getRoutes(), routeFilter.get(i).getTitle(),routeFilter.get(i).getDescription(), routeFilter.get(i).getImage());
                        filters.add(r);
                    }
                }
                results.count = filters.size();
                results.values = filters; //filters array list "routeFilter"


            }else {
                results.count = routeFilter.size();
                results.values = routeFilter;
            }



            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            routes = (ArrayList<Route>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();//refresh the list view


        }
    }
}
```

This is the new Fragement.java I want to display the list on:

```
package com.example.jermaine.jutc;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class HomePage extends ListFragment {
    ListView lv; // creating a list view variable in main activity
    SearchView sv; // declaring a search text box


    String busNumber[] ={"1", "1A", "3", "3A",
            "3AX", "4", "6", "8",
            "8A", "8AX", "12", "12A",
            "16", "16A", "16B", "16BX",
            "17", "17A", "17AX", "17EX",
            "18", "18A", "19AX", "20",
            "20A", "20AX", "42", "53",
            "54", "101", "103", "121",
            "123", "124", "125", "126",
            "127", "128", "129", "130",
            "295", "301", "303", "308",
            "312", "314", "315", "316",
            "317", "318", "319", "320",


    };



    String letterList[] ={"Hellshire To City", "Hellshire To HWT", "Christian Garden To City", "Christian Garden To HWT",
            "CHRISTIAN GARDEN", "GREATER PORTMORE", "NAGGO HEAD", "NAGGO HEAD",
            "NAGGO HEAD", "NAGGO HEAD", "NAGGO HEAD", "NAGGO HEAD",
            "GREATER PORTMORE", "GREATER PORTMORE", "GREATER PORTMORE", "GREATER PORTMORE",
            "GREATER PORTMORE", "GREATER PORTMORE", "GREATER PORTMORE", "GREATER PORTMORE",
            "GREATER PORTMORE", "GREATER PORTMORE", "GREATER PORTMORE", "GREATER PORTMORE",
            "GREATER PORTMORE", "GREATER PORTMORE", "CONSTANT SPRING", "ABOVE ROCKS",
            "BORDER", "GREATER PORTMORE", "SPANISH TOWN", "INSWOOD VILLAGE",
            "ENSOME ACRES", "EBONY VALE", "GREEN ACRES", "WHITE WATERS",
            "ANGELS/ELTHAM", "ANGELS", "ANGELS/ELTHAM", "LONGVILLE",
            "HARBOUR VIEW", "HELLSHIRE", "CHRISTIAN GARDENS", "NAGOO HEAD",
            "CUMBERLAND", "CUMBERLAND", "CITY", "GREATER PORTMORE",
            "GREATERR PORTMORE", "GREATERR PORTMORE", "GREATERR PORTMORE", "GREATERR PORTMORE"


    }; // array for the bus title



    String desList[] ={"(via)", "(via)Naggo Head->Dawkins Dr->Three Miles", "(via)Waterford->Dawkins Dr->Portmore Toll->Marcus Garvey Dr", "NAGGO HEAD",
            "CHRISTIAN GARDEN", "GREATER PORTMORE", "NAGGO HEAD", "NAGGO HEAD",
            "NAGGO HEAD", "NAGGO HEAD", "NAGGO HEAD", "NAGGO HEAD",
            "GREATER PORTMORE", "GREATER PORTMORE", "GREATER PORTMORE", "GREATER PORTMORE",
            "GREATER PORTMORE", "GREATER PORTMORE", "GREATER PORTMORE", "GREATER PORTMORE",
            "GREATER PORTMORE", "GREATER PORTMORE", "GREATER PORTMORE", "GREATER PORTMORE",
            "GREATER PORTMORE", "GREATER PORTMORE", "CONSTANT SPRING", "ABOVE ROCKS",
            "BORDER", "GREATER PORTMORE", "SPANISH TOWN", "INSWOOD VILLAGE",
            "ENSOME ACRES", "EBONY VALE", "GREEN ACRES", "WHITE WATERS",
            "ANGELS/ELTHAM", "ANGELS", "ANGELS/ELTHAM", "LONGVILLE",
            "HARBOUR VIEW", "HELLSHIRE", "CHRISTIAN GARDENS", "NAGOO HEAD",
            "CUMBERLAND", "CUMBERLAND", "CITY", "GREATER PORTMORE",
            "GREATERR PORTMORE", "GREATERR PORTMORE", "GREATERR PORTMORE", "GREATERR PORTMORE"





    };// array for the  bus route






    int lettersIcon[] = {R.drawable.one, R.drawable.onea, R.drawable.three, R.drawable.threea,
            R.drawable.threeax, R.drawable.four, R.drawable.six, R.drawable.eight,
            R.drawable.eighta, R.drawable.eightax, R.drawable.twelve, R.drawable.twelvea,
            R.drawable.sixteen, R.drawable.sixteena, R.drawable.sixteenb, R.drawable.sixteenbx,
            R.drawable.seventeen, R.drawable.seventeena, R.drawable.seventeenax, R.drawable.seventeenex,
            R.drawable.eighteen, R.drawable.eighteenax, R.drawable.nineteenax, R.drawable.twenty,
            R.drawable.twentya, R.drawable.twentyax, R.drawable.fourtwo, R.drawable.fivethree,
            R.drawable.fivefour, R.drawable.oneoone, R.drawable.oneothree, R.drawable.onetwoone,
            R.drawable.onetwothree, R.drawable.onetwofour, R.drawable.onetwofive, R.drawable.onetwosix,
            R.drawable.onetwoseven, R.drawable.onetwoeight, R.drawable.onetwonine, R.drawable.onethreezero,
            R.drawable.twoningfive, R.drawable.threeoone, R.drawable.threeothree, R.drawable.threeoeight,
            R.drawable.threetwelve, R.drawable.threefourteen, R.drawable.threefifteen, R.drawable.threesixteen,
            R.drawable.threeseventeen, R.drawable.threeeighteen, R.drawable.threenineteen, R.drawable.threetwenty

    }; // array of image bus numbers




    private ArrayList<Route> getRoutes()
    {
        ArrayList<Route> routes = new ArrayList<>();
        Route r;

        for(int i=0; i<busNumber.length; i++)
        {
            r = new Route(busNumber[i], letterList[i], desList[i], lettersIcon[i]);
            routes.add(r);
        }
        return routes;


    }//to fill the array with values from defined arrays


    public HomePage() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View homeView ;
        homeView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_page, container, false);


        //assigning a my_listview (listview) located in my_listview.xml file

       lv = (ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.my_listview);
        sv = (SearchView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.txtsearch);

        // declaring a new ListAdapter and assigning the arrays in it
        final ListAdapter adapter = new ListAdapter(getActivity(),getRoutes());
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);




        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return homeView;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

your listview and searchview is in the homeview ,so you should call home view to find them like:

```
 lv = (ListView)homeView.findViewById(R.id.my_listview);
 sv = (SearchView)homeView.findViewById(R.id.txtsearch);
```

Comment: It is still crashing after I made the corrections

Comment: I got it to work thank you

Comment: glad to help :) @JermaineGuyjagharsinghe